# Finding GB Designs

Tags: design-patent

I'm having trouble locating the pdf for what seems to be a GB Design which google patents indicates exist. Espacenet can't find it, Designview can't find it, there's no text/images in google patents.

Im probably using the wrong tools, but does anybody know which database to use?

An example would be [GB201301573D0](https://patents.google.com/patent/GB201301573D0/en?oq=GB201301573D0), though the one I'm looking for doesn't have any family members, so going through them is not an option.

Comment: Can you provide the desired patent number?

Comment: @EricShain not really, but I just changed a few digits to getthe example in the question

Comment: Are you sure this is a design and not a utility patent. The US equivalent to the linked document is clearly a utility patent.

Comment: The most recent listing in the  https://www.gov.uk/check-the-design-journal is 6039937 Universal Smart Phone Magnetic Holder. That doesn't look like the same type of number as GB201301573D0

Comment: If the number starts with GB  than may try https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum

Comment: @EricShain I thought it was a design for the D in the kind code, but you're right.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite yes, AD found the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number starts with GB  than can be  found https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum also. But can not be found anywhere if ending with D0 as clarified in this link https://wiki.piug.org/display/PIUG/GB+patents+with+D0+kind+code. (Because D0 identifies that an GB application was filed, but the application is not (yet) published). This seems to solve the riddle you are facing.

Comment: I included a short summary of the information in the link.